# Is there a computer-readable Hiberno-English pronunciation dictionary?

Tags: phonology, computational-linguistics, resource-request

For American English, there's the [CMUDict](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict#about), but is there one for Irish pronunciation?

If there isn't, is there a way to translate American to Irish pronunciation?

Answer (score 2):

Raymond Hickey's *The phonology of Irish English* is a good place to start although there is no computer-readable one that I know of. *A Sound Atlas of Irish English* by the same author may be the closest thing.